# Security and email groups that are created from an external database don't work until the doc is saved

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a Notes agent that pulls data from a postgres db.  It pulls names, region and roles from the database and builds a 2 types of groups: email and security.  They get created fine but when I try to use them they don't work -- email sent to email group is not delivered and the security group just doesn't work.  That is until I open and save the group doc.  Then everything works fine.  I'm suspecting it's one or more fields that are not being set but I don't know which ones.  When I create the groups, I set the name, 'type' and 'group type' and, of course, the member list.  Anyone know what might be missing?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared the docs in NotesPeek before and after you open and re-save them? Are any new computed fields added? Are any field types changed?  If so, calling NotesDocument.ComputeWithForm before you save the document in your agent should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Rich,  thanks.  I did try ComputeWithForm but that didn't make a  difference.  I did see that there were additional fields before and after save.  But didn't know which ones to add.  I ended up using NotesPeek as it was a clearer display then my own home-grown document field 'peek' tool.  I added several of the fields and it worked!  Not sure which fields made the difference but it's working now.  Thanks for reminding me of NotesPeek.

Clem